# Ubuntu 22.04 stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, mount

My computer won't boot.

I've tried:

- Purge Nvidia drivers
- Start with `nomodeset`
- `fsck` (It didn't run because `/dev/sda3` was always mounted.)
- `apt update`
- Removing `quiet splash *`

Results of `journalctl` :

[image]

Results of `fsck -nf` :

[image]

With `quiet splash` removed the PC booted until `[ OK ]Reached target Multi-User System.`, but nothing else happened after that.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed, needed to reinstall Ubuntu desktop after purging Nvidia drivers